# What does 'other' mean, in Section 10 of the 'Constitution Act, 1867'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntax

<sub>Source: p 37, *The Canadian Constitution* (2013) by Prof Adam Dodek [BA JD LLM](https://commonlaw.uottawa.ca/en/people/dodek-adam).</sub>

> [ [Original Source :](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/CONST/FullText.html) ] Application of Provisions referring to Governor General
>
> 10. The Provisions of this Act referring to the Governor General extend and apply to the Governor General for the Time being of Canada, or **other** the Chief Executive Officer or Administrator for the Time being carrying on the Government of Canada on behalf and in the Name of the Queen, by whatever Title he is designated.

I suspect the obsolescence of the 1867 syntax as my problem, because the above is from the [*Constitution Act, 1867*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_Act,_1867). 
I cannot even determine whether **other** here is a pronoun or adjective.

Comment: Maybe obsolescence. In modern thinking context, I would use "otherwise" in place of "other", if it holds the meaning.

Comment: 'otherwise' is used a number of times throughout the Act, but this exact wording is also in section 62.

Comment: @useruser3169 I agree with the two comments above; I too glossed it as 'otherwise' but I thought to question this usage for certainty in such an important document.